# PLSQL "give" script but not allow users to read

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, obfuscation

I'm new to pl/sql and my question is: is it possible to "compile" a script in sql plus or sql developer and give the file to other person in order to allow other to execute the code but not allowing them to read the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about the [Oracle wrap utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/c_wrap.htm) (a separate command-line application that is part of your Oracle client install and not a part of SQL Developer) or the [dbms_ddl.wrap function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_ddl.htm#CBHGIDEG) which you could invoke from SQL Developer.  These create obfuscated statements that will create a stored procedure (or package or function) that behaves normally but where the text in the data dictionary is not human readable.  The wrap utility doesn't provide perfect security-- there are unwrapping tools and presentations on the internet that would let an attacker unwrap the code you hand them.  And you can often figure out what the unwrapped code is really doing by looking at other data dictionary views (`v$sql` will show the unwrapped SQL statements that are executed for example) or by tracing a session.

Answer (score 0):

It depends also of definition of the word give. You can store PL/SQL code in the database. Give users right to execute it, to see the source code of the package header, but not to see the source of package body. But of course DBAs can read it, They can also trace it (even if it is wrapped).

Also note that PL/SQL packages are wrapped in a different way than PL/SQL procedures. As of 11g packages are wrapped using simple one-to-one byte substitution. While for PL/SQL procedures, there is stored obfuscated bytecode of DIANA virtual machine. AFAIK there is no accessible unwrap for PL/SQL procedures, it is much harder to reverse engineer.